# How do I replace a portion of NA's in a column with the mean of a grouping variable?

Tags: r, replace, na, missing-data

I have a dataset with Length and size variables. I have found the mean lengths of the size variables; spat=29.5, small=59.35, and market=97.0. I have also found the proportions of measured values spat=11%, small=38%, and market=50% for each of the size groupings.

I would like to fill in the un measured (na) lengths in the data set based on the proportions given above and assign each proportion a  length based on the means given above.

for example 11% of the na's will be replaced with 29.5 length, 38% will be replaced with 59.35, and 50% will be replaced with 97.0

Does anyone know the code to make this work?

I'm sorry if I'm missing something, this is my first time asking a question.

```r
     Length   size 
    NA        NA
    68         Small    
   NA         NA  
    84        Market    
    NA        NA  
    75        Small    
    81        Market    
    NA        NA   
     32        Spat    
     28        Spat    
     18        Spat    
      NA      NA   
      21       Spat    
      30       Spat    
      NA      NA
```

Comment: Please share a little bit of sample data, ~20 rows is plenty. `dput()` is the nicest way to share data because it is copy/pasteable, try `dput(your_data[1:20, ])` (or pick a different subset so that there are enough `NA` values to make it a good example).

Comment: I tried the dput and i'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I edited the data into the original post

Comment: That looks promising, but is missing a little bit. The `dput()` should start with `structure(` to be fully copy/pasteable.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little long, but it should do the work.

```
sizes = unique(size)[!is.na(unique(size))]
props = c(1:length(sizes))
for (i in 1:length(sizes)) props[i] = length(Length[which(size == sizes[i])]) / length(Length[!is.na(Length)])
means = c(1:length(sizes))
for (i in 1:length(sizes)) means[i] = mean(Length[which(size == sizes[i])])

idx = round(cumsum(props) * sum(is.na(size)))
nass = c()
nals = c()
for (i in 1:length(idx)) nass = append(nass, rep(sizes[i], (idx[i] - length(nass))))
for (i in 1:length(idx)) nals = append(nals, rep(means[i], (idx[i] - length(nals))))
size[is.na(size)] = nass
Length[is.na(Length)] = nals
```

Let me explain what I do here. The following line gets all unique sizes into an array:

```
sizes = unique(size)[!is.na(unique(size))]
```

The following loop calculates the proportion of sizes that are not null.

```
props = c(1:length(sizes))
for (i in 1:length(sizes)) props[i] = length(Length[which(size == sizes[i])]) / length(Length[!is.na(Length)])
```

The following loop calculates the means for each size.

```
means = c(1:length(sizes))
for (i in 1:length(sizes)) means[i] = mean(Length[which(size == sizes[i])])
```

The following line calculates the number of missing (NA) cases that we need to fill proportionate to the non missing size values.

```
idx = round(cumsum(props) * sum(is.na(size)))
```

The following two loops creates the new values that we will input to the original dataset.

```
nass = c()
nals = c()
for (i in 1:length(idx)) nass = append(nass, rep(sizes[i], (idx[i] - length(nass))))
for (i in 1:length(idx)) nals = append(nals, rep(means[i], (idx[i] - length(nals))))
```

Finally we paste these new values to the original vectors (i.e., size and Length)

```
size[is.na(size)] = nass
Length[is.na(Length)] = nals
```

Comment: Hello, Your code works well, but now I want to know how I could tweak it to do this exact same thing, get the lengths proportions by group ( a different variable). So the missing values in each specific group would be filled in by the proportions of the measured oysters.

Comment: You can change the variable names. In this example, they were "size" and "Length". Just change those names to do the same thing for different variables.

Comment: You misunderstood me I think. The grouping has no missing values and I want to do exactly what the code is doing now, but instead of not having a specific grouping, I want to have it per sample so that the missing variables are evenly distributed among samples

Answer (score 0):

The following function does what the question asks for.
The format the values to be assigned is in is not clear, I assume a *named vector*.

The result is a named list, with members `x`, the new values, and `groups`, the new group variable values.

```
fill_perc <- function(x, groups, prob, values){
  stopifnot(length(prob) == length(values))
  prob <- prob/sum(prob)
  i <- which(is.na(x))
  j <- sample(length(values), size = length(i), prob = prob, replace = TRUE)
  x[i] <- values[j]
  groups[i] <- names(values)[j]
  list(x = x, groups = groups)
}

P <- c(11.8, 38, 50)
V <- setNames(c(29.5, 59.35, 97), c("Spat", "Small", "Market"))

set.seed(2020)
fill_perc(Length, size, P, V)
#$x
# [1]  81.00  66.00  44.00  59.35  29.00  24.00  68.00  97.00  92.00  21.00
#[11]  28.00  25.00  59.35  97.00  34.00  91.00  97.00  65.00  58.00 110.00
#[21]  52.00  48.00  96.00  95.00  54.00  40.00  98.00  63.00 138.00  30.00
#[31] 110.00
#
#$groups
# [1] "Market" "Small"  "Small"  "Small"  "Spat"   "Spat"   "Small"  "Market"
# [9] "Market" "Spat"   "Spat"   "Spat"   "Small"  "Market" "Spat"   "Market"
#[17] "Market" "Small"  "Small"  "Market" "Small"  "Small"  "Market" "Market"
#[25] "Small"  "Small"  "Market" "Small"  "Market" "Spat"   "Market"
```